# Create an MSI (Wix tool) that download from a uri and unzip

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, exe, tar

I'm new to C# / Visual Studio and Wix tool. I've been doing some tutorials about Wix (.xaml etc.) and I need some help!

Here is the main idea: I want to download a tgz from an uri (the file can change - *not the uri*), then unzip this file in a tar and unzip again.

At the begining I made an msi that generate an .exe file, this .exe have a download button with a progress bar. But as you can guess there is some useless steps. Why not download directly in the msi?

**My questions are:**

- Is there an easier way (meaning downloading directly in the msi the target file from the uri) ?
- How would you do that?

Thanks in advance,

Happy coding,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSI doesn't like this.  The two main problems are file/folder permissions and the concept that what MSI installs, MSI wants to monitor/repair/upgrade/service.  If you really want an "evergreen" pattern  I recommend  handling it in the app.  Have MSI install an EXE with a base archive and have the EXE extract the archive to the userprofile dirctory on first run and call it.  The EXE can also look for updated archives and download them to the user profile and extract as needed.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I've been working on the exe. I have another question, here is the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005747/c-sharp-progress-bar-stays-to-0-while-the-download-works-webclient

Comment: It's customary to accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a WiX Custom Action in C#.
[Creating WiX Custom Actions in C# and Passing Parameters](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jschaffe/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters/)